# Existem Usuários Anônimos?

Tags: debate

Na fila de edições sugeridas, me deparei com o seguinte cenário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que seria esse usuário anônimo?

Comment: O cara estava deslogado.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sim, todo mundo que não cria uma conta ou faz o *login* é um usuário anônimo. Tem restrições do que ele pode fazer e raramente eles fazem mais que navegar pelo site, mas quando ele faz aparece isto aí. Os moderadores tem acesso ao padrão de uso do usuário se for necessário, mas tem pouco identificação de quem é, só é usada em casos graves de violação dos termos de uso do site ou algo parecido.

Answer (score 11):

Qualquer visitante sem sessão iniciada pode propor alterações a publicações, carregando em "**melhorar esta pergunta/resposta**:"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]