# Sugestão de edição por usuário anônimo

Tags: debate, edição, duvida

Realizando algumas análises de sugestão de [edição de pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) me deparei com uma sugestão de edição por um usuário anônimo, como isso é possível?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### @edit

Ao acessar uma pergunta sem estar logado, só é exibido a opção de *compartilhar* a pergunta. Por isso a dúvida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que isso não seria possível?

Comment: Possível duplicado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7432/23291

Comment: @Maniero, abri uma aba anonima para simular um acesso sem estar logado, porém, a única opção possível era a de `compartilhar` mostrado no *@edit*.

Comment: Irei fechar a pergunta @JNat e hkotsubo, só queria entender como simular essa situação.

Comment: Há perguntas que é liberado a opção [melhorar esta pergunta](https://i.imgur.com/8y0h8UH.png) que permite sugerir uma edição mesmo sem estar logado.

Comment: Não me lembro dos específicos, mas tenta [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/389264/angular-e-nodejs), por exemplo, @AndréFilipe ;)

Comment: @AndréFilipe Se não me engano, o link para editar anonimamente só aparece se não tiver nenhuma edição pendente. E para perguntas novas, ele só aparece depois de X minutos (carece de fontes, mas vou procurar algum FAQ que mencione isso). Vc tentou ver mais de uma pergunta pra ver se em alguma aparece o link para editá-las? Pois para mim, aparecem normalmente (fiz o mesmo teste que vc, em uma aba anônima)

Comment: Não testei em outras perguntas. Provavelmente deve ter ocorrido este cenário em uma pergunta recente.

Comment: Tem mesmo um timeout até que apareça o link de "melhorar" para usuários anônimos. Parece que é de 10 minutos. Ver resposta em https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work

Comment: @bfavaretto Não foi essa a ideia que eu tirei da citação original - "Anonymous users can suggest edits to any post more than 10 minutes old". O que interpreto é que o post tem que ter sido criado à pelo menos 10 minutos.

Comment: @Isac foi isso que eu quis dizer